# A good framework for easily creating a social networking site

Tags: social-networking

I was just reading about [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/), a free framework for easily creating an ecommerce site.  I was wondering if anyone knew of a similar, easy to use framework that is designed specifically for social networking sites.

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: on a side note, Magento is perhaps the most unintuitive platform I've ever come across...stay well away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ning.](http://www.ning.com/)

**Edit.**  The Ning business model is, they host your community for free and they get the revenue from adverts on the site.  If you want to host it yourself you can, but you need to license the software.

**Edit 2**  I recommended Ning because I participate in a community hosted there.  A minute's Googling through [Elgg](http://elgg.org/) which seems to be more what you're looking for, but I haven't had an direct experience of it.

Comment: thanks. i looked at ning and it appears you have to host your site through them.  do you know of any frameworks i can install and run on my own server?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen a few people mention MonoX (based on ASP.Net), but I've not had a chance to evaluate it yet myself: http://www.mono-software.com/Pages/MonoX-ASP.NET-Portal-Framework.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Laconi.ca](http://laconi.ca/trac/) (micro-blogging - which could be considered a subset of social networking). It's an open source option on which you could base a project (plugins have already been developed).

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like [JomSocial](http://www.jomsocial.com/), which is built on top of Joomla.

Answer (score 1):

Having just looked at this question again, you might find that [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) is pretty useful in building a social networking site too.

We have recently built a private social network for a client, based on Drupal, and lots of the functionality is a pretty good match, particularly if you include modules such as [User Relationships](http://drupal.org/project/user_relationships) and [Organic Groups](http://drupal.org/project/og).

I hope that helps!