# Creating a new Social Networking site. Recommended framework for starting up?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails-3, drupal, cakephp, social-networking

Okay, so we are now developing a new Social Networking site where users will be able to add content, meet (and add new friends) new people, etc. However, we will also have a rating system like Stackoverflow has (The concept of badges). But there are a lot more features than just these, that we require (For example, retrieving content via Ajax, like on Facebook's more button at the bottom of your NewsFeed) I was thinking of making something from ground up, using CakePHP. But I am also confused if I should modify an existing open source Social Networking engine,like Elgg, instead. Will I be reinventing the wheel if I were to work on CakePHP? Development time is not a factor for me. Also could you contrast between the disadvantages (is security one of them?) between the options that I might possibly have (CakePHP vs Elgg vs Drupal vs anything else). I am more open to anything at this point too, Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

P.S - I know Drupal and Elgg are not frameworks, but to me, they look like viable options as well.

Thank you

Comment: Possible Dupes: [#1337934](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337934/a-good-framework-for-easily-creating-a-social-networking-site), [#818630](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818630/is-it-drupal-good-for-building-social-networking-site), [#3380519](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380519/php-framework-for-social-networking), [#2077056](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077056/social-networking-development-where-to-start)

Comment: @jnpcl - Thanks, but it still hasn't answered my question - Should I work from scratch or should I build from an existing Social Networking engine like Elgg

Comment: I'd actually either use CodeIgniter or start from scratch and borrow some CI libraries. It's the most light weight PHP framework out there while still having a pretty robust feature set (libs and the like).

Comment: Thank you, this was the kind of suggestion I was wanting to hear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The options are as vast as your potential needs for a reason: there isn't a single answer and the solution fitting my needs won't fit yours. I don't have much experience with fully featured engines like Elgg, but as I already know Drupal I know I'll seriously consider [Drupal Commons](http://acquia.com/products-services/drupal-social-business-software). Drupal's learning curve is steep but it worths it. Drupal Commons is not a closed package, it builds and Drupal and its modularity. So you won't end up looking for scarce expertise with only a few good services providers available.

Comment: +1 for the Drupal Commons, though being a Drupal user myself, I've never seen it or come across it till date. Thank you mongo.

Answer (score 2):

Being a Drupal dev myself, I'd say you'd have to consider Ruby on Rails. After all, Twitter was conceived with it as far as I know. Ruby on Rails is designed to get almost any idea fast to market. Drupal is a good content management system. Do yourself a favor and give RoR due consideration.

Comment: Thank You Rimian. I will try out Ruby definitely, infact, I was in a dilemma if I should go with Ruby or not. I heard Ruby wasn't scalable, so I just ignored it. Now I will go back and give it a try :)

Comment: RoR isn't really designed for ultra high speed but it can scale. Unfortunately, I'm not the expert. I do know however, it would scale better than a Drupal application that is struggling to meet requirements. Take a look at Micheal Hartl's tutorial. It mentions scale somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I try to make a social network engine use meteor, [fspace](https://github.com/yozawiratama/freespace) , hope useful. :)